# jQuery: html() function get old data in form

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to read data in a HTML page. On that page, I have a `<form>` element which contains some `<input>` tags for user to enter their values.
When being initialized, this form has some default values for those `<input>` elements. When I submit this form, I use the `html()` method to get the HTML string of current state of this page, but I do not why this result string is still contain old values (default input values), not the new ones.
Is there any way to update or persist the user-entered value to those `<input>` elements before calling `html()`? How can I get the string which contain newest value by using jQuery methods?
Thank you so much!

Comment: Why do you need *to get the HTML string of current state of this page*?

Comment: Why are you using html to get the entire page, seems odd. You should be able to select all of the values from the form using serialize if that's what you're after.

Comment: @VisioN: I have to get this HTML (actually a part of it), then doing some calculations, put some replacements, push and store it on server. Later, I use it to render another page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

However, it is strange what you are trying to do, but all you need is to update the value attribute of the form elements. It can be done with the following code (put it in the form `submit` handler):

```
$("form input").attr("value", function() {
    return this.value;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/BXha6/

Comment: Thank you so much. Actually, your suggestion did not help me solve this problem, but it gave me a clue to go on. I tried the demo you created on jsfiddle, it worked with jQuery 1.7.1, but when I downgrade it to 1.5.2, it caused error ^_^. So I think maybe there's something mysterious in jQuery 1.5.2 that I will research it deeper. I applied your clue to another way:  
`$("form input").attr("defaultValue", function() {  
    return this.value;  
});`  
and it worked great!

Answer (score 3):

By default the jQuery `html()` function will preserve the `defaultValue` and `defaultChecked` properties rather than using the current values/selections (just as JavaScript `innerHTML` does). To get around this you need to first use the jQuery `prop()`: [Read the Documentation on prop()](http://api.jquery.com/prop/).

For instance, given the code:

```
<form action='/'>
   <input type='radio' value='1' checked name='first' />
   <input type='radio' value='2' name='first' />

   <input type='checkbox' value='yes' />

   <input type='text' value='Start Text' name='second' />
</form>
```

then

```
   $('form').html()
```

Will always output that exact code, regardless of what values you've added/selected/modified.

To remedy that, just run a function to convert the element's values to properties:

```
$("form input[type='radio']").each(function(){
   if (this.checked){
      $(this).prop("defaultChecked",true);
   } else {
      $(this).prop("defaultChecked",false);
   }
});
$("form input[type='checkbox']").each(function(){
   if (this.checked){
      $(this).prop("defaultChecked",true);
   } else {
      $(this).prop("defaultChecked",false);
   }
});
$("form input[type='text']").each(function(){
   $(this).prop("defaultValue",$(this).val());
});

alert( $(form).html() ); //or var the_code = $(form).html();
```

You'll now have the HTML as your current page state is displaying it.

Answer (score 0):

The textarea bit is a bit different if you were looking for how to do that element type:

```
 $("textarea").html( function() {
    return this.value;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/BXha6/7/